# Fill an n*n array with 1s and 0s

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

So Im trying to fill in array with 1s and 0s given the number of elements in  each row and column. 
for example if i have been given

int Row = {2, 2, 2, 3};

int Column = { 3, 2, 1, 3};

then a possible solution is
1 0 0 1
1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1
1 1 0 1

secondly is there any combination in which a valid solution is not possible even if the sum of both arrays (column and row) are equal. In my case it should be valid because 3+2+1+3=2+2+2+3 but is there any case in which both the sums are equal but there still doesn't exist a stable combination.

Comment: The first part of your question isn't a question, but a description of something you want to do. The second part I don't understand. Either way, try to ask one question at a time. If you have 2 questions, post 2 questions. But make sure they actually are questions and not "please give me code that does what I need".

Answer (score 0):

The answer i found was a greedy approach in which answer each subproblem. So i go column by column and fill in each column depending on the weight of the row.
Remember indexing start with 0
I start with column 0
since row 3 has the highest value (3) i fill it

```
0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0  
1 0 0 0
```

now the row and column array are as follows

```
row = {2,2,2,2}  
column = {2,2,1,3}
```

i keep filling until i can no longer insert more i.e column[0]=0

```
1 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0  
1 0 0 0  

row = {1,2,2,2}  
column={2,2,1,2} 



1 0 0 0  
1 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0  
1 0 0 0



row = {1,1,2,2}  
column={2,1,1,2}
```

now since column[0]==0 i can go to the next column and perform the same procedure again